# Unable to advance time with ShadowSystemClock robolectric

Tags: java, android, kotlin, time, robolectric

I've been trying to advance the time of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a class under test. I know! pass a clock don't use the `System.currentTimeMillis()` directly, unfortunately this is not an option on the code I'm working on.

Anyway, to advance time I've tried using the `ShadowSystemClock`, however this does not seem to be working for me.

I'm using robolectric 4.4

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    sdk = [22],
    application = TestApplication::class,
    shadows = [ShadowSystemClock::class])
class myclass{

    @test 
    fun testOne (){
         functionOne()
         ShadowSystemClock.advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1L))
         functionTwo()
    }
}
```

I've found a few examples through github and have tried implementing these with little success.

Any advice with the ShadowSystemClock class is greatly appreciated.